# Can someone explain Importance Sampling to me?

Tags: simulation, random-walk, importance-sampling

So even the combined efforts of my professor, my book and the internet have not been able to make me understand the concept of Importance Sampling.

I know that it is a way to help with estimating the probability of the occurance of very rare events, however, I have no idea how it works.

For instance, let's assume I start a random walk at $x_0=1$ and $x_i = x_{i-1}+y_i$, where $y_i=1$ with chance $p=0.2$ and $y_i=-1$ with chance $1-p=0.8$.
Therefore, the random walk will probably go to lower values. I am told that IS is useful if we want to estimate the probability that the random walk will reach a high value (for instance, $100$), before reaching $0$ (the chance for this is of course at most $0.2^{100} \approx 1.27 \cdot 10^{-70}$). How would IS help for a problem like this?

Comment: Importance sampling is useful for anytime you can't directly sample directly. Not just "rare"events.

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate.  This site is loaded with information on importance sampling.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of an event $A$ is an integral against a probability density $f$:$$\int_A f(x)\text{d}x$$which can be rewritten as$$\int_A \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x)\text{d}x$$an integral against another probability density $g$. In your example, this means simulating a random walk with different transition probabilities, favouring moves up rather than moves down, e.g., with $p=10^{-2}$.